# What advantage do we get in using xml as a database in Embedded systems?

Tags: c++, c, xml, linux

I have seen recently that people use xml files as a database to store the settings. However, I don't know why exactly is it done. I am from a C/C++, Linux background. Thus, please help me to understand this concept. Any simple C/C++ example will help me to understand it's benefit better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is a very common tool with tons of libraries to handle it. Although it isn't the most beautiful format in the world, it is possible to read and modify it by both hand and program. Probably one want to use it when program configuration modified by some gui or tool. If you intend manual configuration, it's probably better to choose something else, for example ini. This is why linux tools rarely use XML, BTW.

As a C++ programmer you'd probably find interesting the "boost::property_tree" library to deal with configs. Examples of usage included in the documentation. Also it provides with plenty of different backends to store configuration, so you haven't to stick to some one format.